# Is a Model Passed by Reference to Partial Views using Html.Partial()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one layout and three partial views and I am passing whole Model to Partial Views. I am wondering Razor is passing the reference of the model or its copy ?

Layout

```
@model MyCustomModel

<div>@Html.Partial("View1", Model)</div>
<div>@Html.Partial("View2", Model)</div>
<div>@Html.Partial("View3", Model)</div>
```

Best experience is creating partial view specific model in layout model and passing the specific models, but Layout model is really complicated and I can't touch it also because of A/B Testing.

Comment: Your layout model (View Model) shouldn't be complicated, it should be clean and only contain the required properties for a particular view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside is just plain C#, so if `Model` is an `object`, not a `struct` or basic type (like `int`, `bool`), it is 'by reference', and not copied.

In my opinion there is not much to worry about, since a view will **never** change the model, so whether it is copied or not, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Partial` is just a C# method in the end if your model really complicated you using `class` and C# passing `object` varable as reference by default.

One of possible solutions but not very clean is create another model for each PartialView and fill model on your main View.

```
@{
    var PartialViewModel1 = Model.PropertiyThatYouNeed;
    //Init other properties if you need
}

@Html.Partial("View1", PartialViewModel1);
```

So you don't need to touch your main ViewModel.